# PEVerify fails on explicit interface property when the interface is in a Portable Class Library

Tags: c#, reflection.emit, peverify

I'm emitting a class that explicitly implements a simple interface property with a get method.  There are no problems so long as the interface is not defined in a portable class library.  However, when moving the interface to a PCL and using only specific types such as `IEnumerable<int>`, PEVerify will fail.

Looking at *ILDASM -> MetaInfo -> Show*, you would see that both `mscorlib` and `System.Runtime` assembly references are imported.  This occurs during the call to `DefineMethodOverride` (watch `AssemblyBuilder.GetReferencedAssemblies()` to see).  You can also see that IEnumerable`1 is brought in as a TypeRef from both assemblies, which seems to be the problem.

When not separating the interface to a PCL, or when changing the type to something else, it works and the `System.Runtime` reference is not included.  To try `string`, replace `IEnumerable<int>` with `string` in the interface as well as `DefineProperty`/`DefineMethod` calls.

Using a modified example [from MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.typebuilder.definemethodoverride.aspx) as a simplified way to reproduce this issue, drop the code below in a console project and everything works great.  Move `interface I` to a portable class library project and you will see exactly what I mean.

How can I get rid of the PEVerify error?

> Error: MethodImpl's Decl (token=0x0a000001) and Body
>   (token=0x00610072) method signatures do not match. [token:0x19000001]
>   [hr:0x801312F4]

```
public interface I
{
    IEnumerable<int> E { get; }
}

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string name = "DefineMethodOverrideExample";
        AssemblyName asmName = new AssemblyName(name);
        AssemblyBuilder ab = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly(asmName, AssemblyBuilderAccess.RunAndSave);
        ModuleBuilder mb = ab.DefineDynamicModule(name, name + ".dll");
        TypeBuilder tb = mb.DefineType("C", TypeAttributes.Public);
        tb.AddInterfaceImplementation(typeof(I));

        PropertyBuilder prop = tb.DefineProperty("I.E", PropertyAttributes.None, typeof(IEnumerable<int>), Type.EmptyTypes);

        MethodBuilder mbIM = tb.DefineMethod(
            "I.get_E",
            MethodAttributes.Private | MethodAttributes.HideBySig | MethodAttributes.NewSlot | MethodAttributes.Virtual | MethodAttributes.Final | MethodAttributes.SpecialName,
            typeof(IEnumerable<int>),
            Type.EmptyTypes);
        prop.SetGetMethod(mbIM);

        ILGenerator il = mbIM.GetILGenerator();
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldnull);
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

        tb.DefineMethodOverride(mbIM, typeof(I).GetProperty("E").GetGetMethod());

        Type tc = tb.CreateType();

        ab.Save(name + ".dll");
    }
}
```

*(.Net 4.5.1)*

*(PEVerify and ILDASM versions 4.0.30319.33440 from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.1A\bin\NETFX 4.5.1 Tools\x64)*

Thanks!

Comment: This is normal, the [AssemblyVersion] for IEnumerable won't match.  Should work just fine at runtime when the CLR remaps it from 2.0.5.0 to 4.0.0.0, have you tried it?

Comment: Yes it does in fact work, but my concern is that there are some places where verification must succeed.  For example if I used such a type in a lambda expression passed to entity framework, verification is called at runtime on the expression (I think so that it works in partial trust if I remember).

Comment: Well, that's a perceived problem that you completely failed to document in your question.  Come back when it turns real.

Comment: Please address the question without the hostility.  I was not trying to describe all usage scenarios, I asked specifically how to remove the PEVerify error.  This is one of numerous scenarios that cause runtime verification, and this one EF example is in fact presently 'real' in the project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some more comparisons with emitted and compiled examples, as well as digging into the [.NET libraries](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/reflection/emit/modulebuilder.cs,1883), I was able to discover the key distinction was in the call to `ModuleBuilder.DefineMethodOverrideNoLock` -> `GetMethodTokenInternalNoLock` (on the interface), in where there is a test for whether the provided `MethodInfo` is a `RuntimeMethodInfo`.  Ultimately a call to `GetMemberRefOfMethodInfo` causes the inclusion of `System.Runtime`, producing conflicting results for certain types, such as `IEnumerable`.

To solve this in a manner that doesn't require reflecting into private members, you can create a proxy or wrapper that inherits `MethodInfo` which overrides all methods to return results from the original `RuntimeMethodInfo`.  This will cause the ILDASM to show the TypeRef and TypeSpec elements that appear in a compiled (non-emitted) assembly trying to explicitly implement a PCL interface method.  I was able to successfully verify an emitted assembly using this technique.